# use VM03801 SELECT sum([conVehicleQuantity]) ,[vehdtlName]

Tags: sql-server

**Hi every one i need help**

```
use VM03801;

SELECT sum([conVehicleQuantity]) ,[vehdtlName]
FROM [VM03801].[dbo].[tblContent] as tc 
INNER JOIN [VM03801].[dbo].[tblVehicleDetails] as tvd 
   on tc.conVehicleCode = tvd.vehdtlId 
INNER JOIN [VM03801].[dbo].[tblDoc]as td 
   on tc.conDocId = td.docId 
where td.docDocTo = 'stor ' and tvd.vehdtlName ='GMC' group by vehdtlName
```

**I want to print the result of above query**

Comment: print this query? type it in notepad and give a print command by selecting a printer.

Comment: where you want to print in output window?

Comment: i want to print it on paper

Comment: I was trolling, but it came out right. :D

Comment: i want to print the result on paper

Comment: query or result set of the select command?

Comment: i use the code in my database sql sever

Comment: do you want to print the result from sql server management studio?

Comment: yes plz the query return tow column  and many rows

Comment: Ok then. right click the serial number column header in the results tab and click print. Thats all you need